# make a liposome

Tags: mesh, particles, bezier-curves

I'm trying to build a liposome like this:

[image]

I made a single unit like this

[image: lipid]

and used the duplication method described here [How to create a sphere with different ring vertex count by scripting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78817/how-to-create-a-sphere-with-different-ring-vertex-count-by-scripting)
The problem is that what I get is this

[image]

As you can see the little legs are sticking out and not in. Does anyone know if there is a way to change the orientation of the rotation of the object so the legs point inside.

Comment: Did you tried to rotate the object itself and apply rotation?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/97731/1853

Comment: In edit mode change the rotation for the "single unit"

Comment: I got a pretty good results using the particle system. However when I scale the sphere, the single unit doe not scale with the sphere.

Comment: Also try to change the pivot point of the that object to the end where you want the hair particle should be attached from. What it will do is, the hairs which are lying half inside the sphere will be taken out! if you don't know how to change pivot point see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object

Comment: If you don't want the changed pivot point you can reset it. See also [How to reset pivot point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88877/how-to-reset-pivot-point)